# Spark-Cassandra-Connector Issue Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/reader/RowReaderFactory

Tags: cluster, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, big-data, apache-spark

What is going wrong with the Spark Cassandra Connector could you please help to solve this?

Scala File:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}


object SparkTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkTest").getOrCreate()
    println("Hello World2")

    val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd1 = sc.cassandraTable("spark_parallalism_test", "test_table1")
    println(rdd1.first)
    sc.stop()
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

SBT file looks like:

```
name := "SparkTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.12" % "3.0.0"
```

Commands to execute:

```
sbt package

spark-submit --class "SparkTest" --master local[4] target/scala-2.12/sparktest_2.12-1.0.jar
```

Error Log:

```
20/12/28 23:41:57 WARN Utils: Your hostname, subhrangshu-Lenovo-V110-15ISK resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.43.14 instead (on interface wlp2s0)
20/12/28 23:41:57 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/12/28 23:41:57 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/reader/RowReaderFactory
        at SparkTest.main(SparkTest.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.RowReaderFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 13 more
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

What is my mistake in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This question is more for StackOverflow, but I'll answer here.

The main reason is that `sbt package` just compiles your code, but don't put dependencies into resulting Jar file.  either you need to start `spark-submit` with `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0`, or you can do `sbt assembly`, but in this case `spark-sql` needs to be declared as `provided`.

See [documentation for Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) for more details.